# help with dateTime to extract only time

Tags: apex

I have a dateTime field `Session_Date_Time__c`
I want to extract only time from this field.
I have tried using

```
Session_Date_Time__c.time()
```

but it gives the result as

```
 06:22:00.000z
```

But i want the result as

```
06:22:00
```

Any help would be appreeciated.
Thanks in advance!!!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
String s = Session_Date_Time__c.format('HH:mm:ss')
```

The DateTime methods : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm

Comment: Its worth mentioning that `format(dateFormatString)` will return the time in the users local. If the code is executed by 2 users with different locals and the same `DateTime` it will return 2 different times. `format(dateFormatString, timezone)` or `formatGmt(dateFormatString)` could be used if you wanted the time to be consistent regardless of the users local.

Comment: @BarCotter : you're totally right ! Thanks for mentionning it.